# How to make subplots bigger in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to get the subplots bigger and clearer. I am trying to plot different values for a normal probability distribution, before and after the Box-Muller-Transformation.

I am using the following code:

```
i=0
j=1
while (i < len(n)):  
    # Gleichmäßig verteilte Werte zwischen 0 und 1
    u1 = random.rand(n[i])
    u2 = random.rand(n[i])

    # Transformation ausführen
    z1,z2 = gaussian(u1,u2)



    plt.subplot(12,2,i+j)
    hist(u1)
    j += 1
    plt.subplot(12,2,i+j)
    hist(u2)
    j += 1
    plt.subplot(12,2,i+j)
    hist(z1)
    j += 1
    plt.subplot(12,2,i+j)
    hist(z2)
    i += 1

fig = plt.gcf()   
fig.set_size_inches(30, 13)
#fig.tight_layout()
plt.suptitle('test', fontsize=20, y=1.05)
plt.show()
```

Attached is the plots I am getting.[image: subplots]

Comment: Can you make the code example so I can run it on my machine?

Comment: https://scientificallysound.org/2016/06/09/matplotlib-how-to-plot-subplots-of-unequal-sizes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use fig = plt.figure(figsize=(x, y)) to change figure size